# width auto not taking the possible space

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, symfony

I'm working on a Twig HTML Inline Form with Bootstrap and I have a problem there.

One row of the inline Form is build up like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                {{ form_label(form.edition) }}
                                {{ form_widget(form.edition) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                {{ form_label(form.weight) }}
                                {{ form_widget(form.weight) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `form-control` class for the actual fields of the form is this from bootstrap:

```
.form-control {
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075) inset;
    color: #555;
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out 0s, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The `form-inline` class overwrites the `form-control` class of the `form_widget` with the following:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: auto;
```

Now my form looks like this:

[image: inline-form]

There's plenty of space that won't fill up with the fields, any idea how I could change it so that the fields extend correctly?

Comment: Your class hierarchy is a bit messed up. If you want nested columns, the hierarchy must go `container`->`row`->`col*`->`row`->`col*`

Comment: The code you posted isn't that. You have no inner row. Read the Bootstrap docs for best info http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Well if it is like that, then `col*` cannot be a child of `form-group`, only `row`.

Comment: There's no need for the innermost `col-sm-12` I think? They are invalid anyway.

Comment: Actually, the Bootstrap linter may help you with sticking to the rules http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/09/23/bootlint/

Comment: @DavidG The innermost is needed, else positioning would be out of line